# Font awesome 6 icons not showing afte Vite build

Tags: laravel, fonts, font-awesome, vite, font-face

I have a new laravel project and imported Font awesome 6 using npm.

When i run "npm run dev" all icons show up, but after running "npm run build" I get 4 console errors that the fonts are not loaded:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): fa-solid-900-886c8622.woff2

When i go to [www.mysite.com/build/assets/font-file](http://www.mysite.com/build/assets/font-file) it shows the file.

But it looks like it tries to get the font files from [www.mysite.com/assets/font-file](http://www.mysite.com/assets/font-file)

Does anyone have an idea on how to correctly load the font files?

Answer (score 0):

In the vite.config.js I had to change

```
base: '/',
```

Into:

```
base: '/build/',
```